# Not able to see databases after creating new hive metastore

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

I have manually installed hadoop and hive on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. Hive was working fine and I created a few test databases (derby).
On restarting laptop, I found that hive was running but running any command like show databases, it was giving error.

I followed the solutions given web. ie:

1) rename metastore_db to metastore_db.tmp.

2) run schematool to generate new metastore_db

3) remove tmp metastore_db.tmp (Not removing gives error when you run hive)

Now I am able to run hive but on running show databases I see only default database.

Is there any way to add databases I created previously (for exxample /user/hive/warehouse/computersalesdb.db saved in hdfs filesystem) to newly generated metastore?

*** UPDATE ***

On further analysis I found, metastore_db folder is being created where ever I run hive. So this seems to be the cause of problem. The solution is:

1) As advised in comment by @cricket_007 have metastore in mysql or any other rdbms you are using.

2) Always run hive from same folder

3) set property “javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL” to create metastore in specific folder, which is defined in hive-site.xml

Leaving this comment for the benefit of other nubes like me :D

Comment: Well, you can't move the metastore files. You would need to figure out the sequence of query statements to recreate all the metastore information. I recommend that you setup Mysql or Postgres as your metastore before you lose your data again

Comment: after creating database in hive, see database or tablename like `describe formatted databasename`, it will show all belongings detail about it.